# Resize QMainwindow to fit Qdockwidget size

Tags: c++, css, qt, qmainwindow, qdockwidget

I have a `QMainWindow` and a `QDockWidget` nested inside this.

I show some graphs, so the `QDockWidget` expands but the `QMainWindow` keeps it's initial size so i have to resize it using my mouse.

So, how can i make a `QMainWindow` resize to `QDockWidget` size every time?

Comment: If you need to resize main window to the size of containing dock window, why do you need dock window at all?

Comment: i have 2 docks side by side and the one expands.I need all the window to be expanded to this size,particularly it's height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was easy at the end.

I take the `Qsize` of my `QDockWidgets` and i resize my `QMainWIndow` to this.

For example i have 2 QDockWidget side by side so what i do is

```
QSize siz =  Dock->size();
QSize siz2 =  Dock2->size();
resize(siz.width()+siz2.width(),siz.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to rewrite the `resizeEvent` function of the `QDockWidget` widget. For that you need to subclass `QDockWidget`.

```
class MYDockwidget : public QDockWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MYDockwidget(QWidget *parent = 0):
    QDockWidget(parent)
    {}

protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
    {
        QDockWidget::resizeEvent(event);
        // Calulate Main window size here.
        // the main window is accesible
        // through the parent property.
    }
};
```

This approach works, but binds the `QDockWidget`'s resizeEvent to the `QMainWindow`. The proper solution is to emit a signal when the size of the `QDockWidget` change.

For that you will need to define a custom signal and of course you want that signal with information about the event in question, hence our signal will be emited with a `QSize` argument.

```
class MYDockwidget : public QDockWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MYDockwidget(QWidget *parent = 0):
    QDockWidget(parent)
    {}

signals:
    void sizeChanged(QSize);
protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
    {
        QDockWidget::resizeEvent(event);
        emit sizeChanged(event->size());
    }
};
```

After that you can write code like:

```
// Inside your main window.
public slots:
    void on_dock_size_changed(QSize)    

MYDockwidget *dock = new MYDockwidget(this);
connect(dock, SIGNAL(sizeChanged(QSize)), this, SLOT(on_dock_size_changed(QSize)));

void on_dock_size_changed(QSize size)
{
    // resize your main window here.
}
```

**Disadvantage:**

You will need to set the `QDockWidget`'s properties by hand (programmatically) unless you manage your self to insert your custom widget as a QTDesigner plugin.